# Can With (nolock) cause blocking on a select on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2022

we've got third party software running at our company which tends to hang every other day due to SQL blocking. I can see the blocking happen in our monitoring solution and in SSMS but for now I haven't been able to fully explain it.

The blocking always follows the same pattern. At the head of the blocking tree is an insert Query:

```
(@P1 bigint,@P2 int,@P3 numeric(14),@P4 ntext,@P5 ntext,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 ntext,@P11 ntext,@P12 ntext,@P13 ntext,@P14 int)INSERT INTO wmfrLog (dwRunningProcessID, dwStepID, decWhen, szWho, szWhat, dwParam1, dwParam2, dwParam3, dwParam4, szParam1, szParam2, szParam3, szParam4, dwConnectionID) OUTPUT INSERTED.dwID VALUES(@P1, @P2, @P3, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, @P8, @P9, @P10, @P11, @P12, @P13, @P14)
```

The query that gets blocked on this insert is also always the same:

```
select p.szName, p.szDescription, s.szName, s.szDescription, rs.dwID, rs.dwRunningProcessID,rs.szWho,rs.decStarted,rs.dwStatus,rs.dwStepID,rs.decDeadline,rs.dwPriority,rp.szTitle,rs.decActivation,s.dwType,rp.szVariable01,rp.szVariable02,rp.szVariable03,rp.szVariable04,rp.szVariable05,rp.szVariable06,rp.szVariable07,rp.szVariable08,rp.szVariable09,rp.szVariable10,rp.szVariable11,rp.szVariable12,rp.szVariable13,rp.szVariable14,rp.szVariable15,rp.szVariable16,p.dwID  

from wmfrStep rs, wmfStep s, wmfrProcess rp, wmfProcess p  **with (nolock)** 

where (s.dwID=rs.dwStepID) and (rp.dwID=rs.dwRunningProcessID) and (p.dwID=rp.dwProcessID) and (s.dwType in (2, 4)) and (rp.dwStatus = 2) and (rs.dwStatus in (1, 2)) and (rs.szWho IS NULL or rs.szWho=N'' or rs.szWho=N'00000000')  and ( ((s.dwFlags & 2) = 0)  and (rp.dwFlags is NULL or  ((rp.dwFlags & 32) = 0) )) and (rs.decActivation IS NULL or rs.decActivation<=20230911083413)
```

This select query has an LCK_M_S lock. The query being blocked then blocks a whole lot of other select queries. I'm wondering if the "with (nolock)" in the select query can be the cause of this but I'm confused because the insert and select don't "touch" the same tables but nevertheless they're blocking each other. Any steps I can take do to some further analysis?

Comment: The hint is only applying to `wmfProcess` table. What object is the lock belonging to? Any triggers on `wmfrLog`? Or is the insert transaction doing other things inside the same transaction that would acquire locks before that statement?

Comment: At a guess, are `dwRunningProcessID` and `dwStepID`  in `wmfrLog` unindexed foreign keys to `wmfrProcess` and `wmfStep`? If so the insert could be acquiring locks on these tables to check the validity of the inserted values even though they are not part of the insert statement, and as Martin has pointed out, the locking hint would not apply to either of these tables.

Comment: Oh, look at the time, it's 2023 already, you really should move on from the old "comma joins". The hint only applies per table

Comment: Side note: Explicit joins are a part of ANSI SQL standard for over 30 years now. There really is no excuse for using implicit joins (with one exception - when you a full join and it's implied from context).

Comment: As it is "third party software" I doubt the OP here has anything to do with the join syntax being used

Comment: Please share the execution plans of the two queries via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Please also show the full table and index definitions for all tables involved.

Comment: @MartinSmith I looked into our Sql Sentry logging, the lock seems to be to Wait Resource: WMWorkFlow.dbo.wmfrStep.PK_RunningStep
I also checked the database for more info, there isn't one FK's in the DB and also no triggers.

Comment: @GarethD please see my above reply to Martin

Comment: @Charlieface I will try to get hold of the plans, but I can't simulate/trigger the locking, so I have to catch them in the act :-)

Comment: So as the insert to `wmfrLog` doesn't appear related to `wmfrStep` in any way presumably the lock was taken by a previous statement in the same transaction rather than the insert statement that you posted, So that *session* is blocking and it is currently running an insert but the lock itself was taken by an earlier statement

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for your reply. Am I correct in assuming that there's no other way to find out this previous statement than with a trace or an extended event session since I don't have access to the source code of the application.

Comment: yeah most likely